# Issue during migration from Google OAuth 1.0 to OAuth 2.0 - The oAuth client was disabled

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I'm trying to follow the documentation "https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref" to migrate oAuth to oAuth2 but keep getting an error

In the "APIs & auth" - "Credentials" Section in our API developers console  we have 1 Client ID for web application set up along with a number of service account client Ids.

The client Ids appear to be in a format `xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com`  for each client ID that is set up.

If I use the exact Id for the 'client ID for web application' in the format `[xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com`] then I get an error

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_client"
}
```

If I use the more generic client ID [ xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
] then I get the following error

```
    {
        "error" : "disabled_client",
        "error_description" : "The OAuth client was disabled."
    }
```

Here is my post request from Fiddler

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth realm="",oauth_consumer_key="<consumerKey>",oauth_token="<token>",oauth_timestamp="1400680750",oauth_nonce="6637551",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="I%2FCOsR1BrGQHnqTeyhX4GUrKrv8%3D"
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Length: 151
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1&client_id=<clientID>.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={<client_secret>}
```

Here is the base string I use for oauth_signature

```
POST&https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token&client_id=<clientID>.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=<clientSecret>&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1&oauth_consumer_key=<consumerKey>&oauth_nonce=2648138&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1400681371&oauth_token=<token>
```

Here is the response I get from Google

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Wed, 21 May 2014 13:59:16 GMT
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="json.txt"; filename*=UTF-8''json.txt
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

5b
{
  "error" : "disabled_client",
  "error_description" : "The OAuth client was disabled."
}
0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check whether your OAuth 2.0 client type (web application) match the OAuth 1.0 consumer type.

Comment: I've tried to find out what the oAuth 1.0 consumertype is but I'm not sure how to check it.  According to the documentation "An application is identified as a native application if one of the following is *true* : The application has set its native application name, or The application is a Chrome Extension.  </br>
The application is definitely not a Chrome extension and I cant see where the native application name would be set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the POST body that I was sending to google was incorrect.

Originally I had sent

```
grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1&client_id=<clientID>.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={<client_secret>}
```

Note the { } around the client_secret. When I removed these then I no longer got the errors.

Now I can pass in the client_id in the format `xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com` and the client_secret without { } and I get a sucessful response.

The reason for the other error that I had been receiving was that the client id in the format xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com was an old client_id that had been deleted and was no longer visible on the Google Developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Here a related post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-data-export-api/yveoPwSVzCQ

As for Owen's suggestion, I am pretty sure the error is not related to oauth1 vs oauth2 client type validation but rather to the provided oauth2 credentials (client id and client secret).